# Operador ternario '?'

Tags: java, operador

El operador ternario `?` de java me está dando error utilizándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList <String> titleTabs= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <String> countTitleTabs= new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(ArrayList<String> titleTabs, ArrayList<String> countTitleTabs) {

        titleTabs.get(0).isEmpty() ? this.titleTabs.add(0,"----") : this.titleTabs.add(0,titleTabs.get(0));

}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: que significa (accountBalances.getLocked() == null ? Constant.BD_ZERO : accountBalances.getLocked()).toString()); }

Comment: Si la condición accountBalances.getLocked() == null  es TRUE devuelve Constant.BD_ZERO y si es FALSE accountBalances.getLocked()).toString()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El operador ternario `?` también se conoce como **asignación** condicional. Así pues, úsalo para asignar un valor en base a una condición dada.

En tu caso quedaría:

```
this.titleTabs.add(0, (titleTabs.get(0).isEmpty() ? "----" : titleTabs.get(0)));
```

Ya que el primer valor es el mismo en los dos casos, sólo cambia el segundo y la forma de construcción de ese operador es:

```
valorDeseado = (condición)? valorSiSeCumple : valorSi_NO_SeCumple;
```

Answer (score 3):

El operador ternario se usa para devolver un valor, no para realizar operaciones. Tu código debería ser algo así:

```
 valor = titleTabs.get(0).isEmpty()?"----":titleTabs.get(0);
 this.titleTabs.add(0,valor);
```

o

```
this.titleTabs.add(0,titleTabs.get(0).isEmpty()?"----":titleTabs.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

En los casos que me a tocado usarlo lo e usado de la siguiente manera:

```
algunObjetoJson.addProperty("accion",(null != algo.getNombre() ? "<a href="">HolaJuan</a>" : "<a href="">HolaAlguien</a>"));
```

Ambos **`?`** y **`:`** deben asignar un valor seguido de ellos.