# Como usar operador ternario

Tags: java

buenas tardes, tengo una duda muy específica, lo que sucede es que quiero que el usuario ingrese un numero y de acuerdo a este establecer si el vehículo es auto o moto, creo que ya lo logre pero no muy bien, después de esto quiero que si el vehículo es auto entonces le pregunte el modelo al usuario el modelo, de igual manera con la moto, por ejemplo: si es carro entonces que le pregunte de la siguiente manera ("cual es el modelo del carro: "), si es moto de esta manera ("cual es el modelo de la moto: "), espero y me hallan logrado entender, muchísimas gracias de antemano

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vehiculo{

    //atributos

    int Tipo;
    String Placa;
    int Modelo;
    int Km;
    int Cilindraje;
    static final double BASEA = 50.000;
    static final double BASEB = 70.000;
    boolean decidir;
    String decicion;
    boolean decidir2;
    String decicion2;



    // PEDIR DATOS

    public void pedirDatos(){

        Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("introduce un numero del 1 al 3 si tu vehiculo es auto o del 4 al infinito si tu vehiculo es moto");
        Tipo = pedir.nextInt();

        //SI "Tipo" es menor o igual a 3 "decidir" es true
        decidir = (Tipo <= 3);

        decicion = (decidir) ? "Auto" : "Moto";

        System.out.println("Tu vehiculo es: "+ decicion);

        decidir2 = (decicion == "Auto");

        decicion2 = (decidir2) ? System.out.println("Introduce el modelo del auto: );
```

Comment: Te invito a relizar el [tour] David,  también el documento [ask].

Comment: A lo mejor, si tu profesor no quiere que uses un if podrias intentarlo con un switch;así en "case moto" invocas el método que quieras y en "case coche" lo mismo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Operador ternario '?'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46728/operador-ternario)

Answer (score 4):

La mejor solución sería asignar a una variable el nombre del modelo, evaluando mediante un operador ternario el número introducido. O sea:

```
    vehiculoTipo = (vehiculoId <= 3) ? "Auto" : "Moto";
```

Luego, puedes usar `vehiculoTipo` en la salida por pantalla del siguiente modo:

```
    System.out.println("Introduce el modelo de tu " + vehiculoTipo);
```

Ya está, con eso queda resuelto el problema, cuando sea un auto,  te imprimirá esto:

```
Introduce el modelo de tu Auto
```

y cuando sea una moto, esto:

```
Introduce el modelo de tu Moto
```

Veamos un ejemplo completo. Nótese que he dado nombres más descriptivos a las variables, implementando además una convención de nombres. De lo contrario estás rápidamente perdido en el código y ni sabes que hacer con las variables.

```
    int vehiculoId;
    String vehiculoTipo;
    String vehiculoPlaca;
    int vehiculoModelo;
    int vehiculoKm;
    int vehiculoCilindraje;

    System.out.println("introduce un numero del 1 al 3 si tu vehiculo es auto o del 4 al infinito si tu vehiculo es moto: ");
    Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
    vehiculoId = pedir.nextInt();
    vehiculoTipo = (vehiculoId <= 3) ? "Auto" : "Moto";
    System.out.println("Introduce el modelo de tu " + vehiculoTipo);
    vehiculoModelo = pedir.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Has introducido un vehículo del tipo: " + vehiculoTipo + " / Modelo: " + vehiculoModelo);
    pedir.close();
```

***Salida prueba 1:***

```
introduce un numero del 1 al 3 si tu vehiculo es auto o del 4 al infinito si tu vehiculo es moto: 
1
Introduce el modelo de tu Auto
1972
Has introducido un vehículo del tipo: Auto / Modelo: 1972
```

***Salida prueba 2:***

```
introduce un numero del 1 al 3 si tu vehiculo es auto o del 4 al infinito si tu vehiculo es moto: 
8
Introduce el modelo de tu Moto
2018
Has introducido un vehículo del tipo: Moto / Modelo: 2018
```

Answer (score 2):

La operacion ternaria es correcta:

```
decidir = (Tipo <= 3);

decicion = (decidir) ? "Auto" : "Moto";
```

Obtienes un valor tipo String a partir del valor de la variable boolean `decidir`.

Pero para imprimir el valor de `Auto` o `Moto` sin usar un `if`, debes usar:

```
System.out.println("Tu vehiculo es: "+ ((decidir) ? "Auto" : "Moto"));
```

---

Otro detalle es que posteriormente estas realizando una comparación incorrecta de valores tipo String:

```
decidir2 = (decicion == "Auto");
```

Debes usar el método .equals() de esta forma:

```
decidir2 = (decicion.equals("Auto"));
```

De esta forma obtendrías un valor boolean de acuerdo a la comparación de valores tipo String.

Answer (score 0):

El operador ternario sirve como una expresión que permite **devolver un valor**. Es decir, el uso del operador ternario es para asignar un valor a una variable. Ejemplo (basado en tu código):

```
decicion = (decidir) ? "Auto" : "Moto";
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que el operador ternario **no reemplaza un `if`**. Este es el problema que tienes aquí:

```
//mal uso de operador ternario
decicion2 = (decidir2) ? System.out.println("Introduce el modelo del auto: );
```

En estos casos, lo mejor es usar un `if`:

```
if (decidir) {
    System.out.println("Introduce el modelo del auto: );
    decicion2 = pedir.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: ¿se puede llegar a hacer una introduccion de datos estando dentro de un operador ternario?, porque la idea que tenia nuestro profesor era que no utilizaramos if

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es algo como `decision2 = decidir ? pedir.nextLine() : "otro valor"`. Recuerda que el operador ternario **no reemplaza un `if`**. Puede que tu profesor esté pidiendo otra cosa y no lo estemos comprendiendo por la descripción del problema o que esté pidiendo algo que no se pueda.

Comment: ¿como invocaria un metodo desde el operador ternario?, porque de acuerdo a si es auto o moto, necesito invocar un metodo u otro.

Comment: En este caso el operador es asi `(condicion) ? metodo1() : metodo2()`