# Duda con evaluación de código en Android

Tags: android

Tengo este codigo en mi app, pero no entiendo cómo se evalúa:
 `return chatBubble.myMessage() ? 1 : 0;`,

Alguien me podria decir como es esto?

```
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    ChatBubble chatBubble = messages.get(position);
    return chatBubble.myMessage() ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eso se llama en Java *Operador ternario*, representando por el símbolo `?`.

Según la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

> Se puede considerar como una forma abreviada de una sentencia
>   `if-then-else`. Este operador también se conoce como el *operador
>   ternario* porque utiliza tres operandos.

Trabaja así en este caso:

- Si el resultado de `chatBubble.myMessage()` es verdadero, retorna `1`
- Si el resultado de `chatBubble.myMessage()` es falso, retorna `0`

El operador ternario tiene entonces tres partes:

```
chatBubble.myMessage()      ?             1           :           0;
        ^                   ^             ^                       ^
   Operando 1                         Operando 2              Operando 3
Expresión a evaluar      Operador    Si Expr es TRUE        Si Expr es FALSE
```

Las expresiones para este operador se escriben así:

A la izquierda de <kbd>`?`</kbd> se pone la expresión o valor a evaluar (*Expr*), a la izquierda de <kbd>`:`</kbd> se pone el valor resultante en caso de que la evaluación de *Expr* sea verdadero, a la derecha de  <kbd>`:`</kbd> se pone el valor resultante en caso de que la evaluación de Expr sea falso.

Y dado que lo usas con `return`, te devolverá el resultado `1` o `0` que haya salido de la evaluación.

- Pregunta relacionada: [Como usar operador ternario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/97599/29967)

**NOTA:**

Esta es la forma más simple de operador ternario. Hay evaluaciones más complejas, operadores anidados etc. Lo cierto es que simplifican muchísimo el código.

En esa sola línea, evalúas algo que de otro modo tendría que ser escrito así:

```
if ( chatBubble.myMessage() ) {
    return 1;
} else { 
    return 0;
}
```

Hablamos de cambiar 5 líneas de código por una sola, gracias al operador ternario.